# Interaction of neutron with matter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interactions

Let's put a quantity of polonium (Po) metal and we throw it by neutron with energy greater than 2 MeV since the neutron is uncharged and does not react to the electron cloud of atoms.

My question is how we can know the probability that the neutron may hit(bump) with a least one polonium nuclei? Are there some article or book talk about this experiment.

Comment: Define "hit". But, one can go to your local ENDF (Evaluated Nuclear Data File) servers and get a wide range of scattering cross sections for neutron interactions with polonium. The thermal neutron cross section on Po-209 is about 1000 barns.

Comment: But if we change of direction of throwing  the neutron is the probality change .for example we don't throw it in direct line we change direction  by some angle $\alpha$

Comment: The variation of scattering angle with impact parameter is the differential cross section. In contrast, the total cross sections are not impacted (pun intended). You don't get to throw neutrons 'in a direct line' at a given nucleus, you throw neutrons at a bunch of atoms and hope something happens.

Comment: I mean change the angle of throwing before collision of atoms .do you have good reference talk about this expirement with mathematical interepretation

Comment: You need to read up more carefully about what scattering cross sections mean.